# 2D Array(Ragged) - Print Each Column Sum

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to calculate the column-wise sum of a 2D array.

For this 2D array:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
```

I have no trouble printing each column sum.

Here is my code which does that

```
int total;
for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++)
{
  total = 0;
  for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    total += array[row][col];
  System.out.println("Column " + col + " total: " + total);
}
```

But, for this ragged 2D array:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2},{5,6,7},{9,10,11,12}};
```

I can't seem to print the last two columns without getting an *outofboundsexception* error. Our professor hasn't really taught us the try and catch statements, so I'm assuming that there must  be a small adjustment of some sort. However, I've already tampered with the above code to print the last two columns but no luck...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int total;
int max = //This is the max number of column one row can have 
for (int col = 0; col < max; col++)
{
  total = 0;
  for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    if(col < array[row].length)//Check for row length here.
       total += array[row][col];
  System.out.println("Column " + col + " total: " + total);
}
```

Basically, you need to check for the length of the row first, before accessing its element.

To find max:

```
int max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    max = Math.max(array[i].length, max);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! But `max` can only be a fixed value? It can't be a value such as array.length?

Comment: @user3718591 look at my updated answer, you need to iterate through all the rows, to find max value of column :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to catch any exceptions. First you should find out what is the longest row in the 2D array (you need a preliminary loop for that).

Suppose it's x. Then you iterate in your outer loop from 0 to x-1, and in your inner loop, before accessing `array[row][col]`, you make sure that `array[row].length > col`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the proper code of the program:: I have learnt from above helping material but I was getting error due to codes were in bits and pieces and especially max value were taken the max (if we need lower number of max in the next counter then this program was failing)

```
package arrayPractice;

public class SumColumArray {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int [][] matrix = new int [5][];
            matrix[0] = new int[2];
            matrix[1] = new int[3];
            matrix[2] = new int[4];
            matrix[3] = new int[2];
            matrix[4] = new int[1];


    int total = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
    max = matrix[row].length; // Variable Length of Column Accessing 
    System.out.println(max);
    for(int column = 0; column < max; column++){
    total = 0;
    matrix[row][column] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    if(column < matrix[row].length);
    total += matrix[row][column];
    System.out.println("Column " + column + " total: " + total);

    }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your professor may not accept this because he hasn't taught you this (yet), but the most elegant solution is to let Java make the low-level looping decisions for itself. You can do this with the [for-each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
int total = 0;
int iterator = 0; // this variable is only necessary if you need to know which row you're in
for (int[] row : array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int item : row) {
        sum += item;
    }
    System.out.println("Column " + iterator + " total: " + sum);
    total += sum;
    iterator++;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

The way it works is that you specify an array and the type of its elements. So an `int[][]` is an array of `int[]`, that's why you specify `for (int[] row : array)`. You can read it as "for each one-dimensional `row[]` in this two-dimensional `array[][]`". Within the loop, you nest another loop over each `int` of the `row[]`.